# What are the detriments of not setting MSFTDATA flag when making a exFAT partition?

Tags: partition, parted, mbr, exfat

I have several external HDDs that I backup data to and occasionally plugin internally when I need access to the data.

I erased all partitions by making a new GPT partition table on the disk.
I made a primary partition of type NTFS and then formatted as an exFAT partition:

```
parted mkpart primary NTFS 0% 100%
mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1
```

Now, I can plug this HDD into both my Unix desktop and Windows desktop and can access the files without issue.

However, I noticed that my Windows partitions have MSFTDATA flag set when viewed in parted (`parted print all`).

**I haven't set this flag** - will this become an issue later and will setting the flag cause issues accessing the data from Unix?
What exactly does Windows (or Unix) use this flag for?

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* a flag per se, this is a GUID associated with [Microsoft basic data partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition) on a *GPT* partitioned disk.

Comment: I am using GPT not MBR.